# How can I set up Samba with LDAP auth for server in workgroup only?

Tags: samba, openldap

https://serverfault.com/questions/ask?title=samba%20ldap%20workgroup%20only

We have quite a few linux machines running SAMBA as standalone servers and are currently just replicating a smbpasswd file from the one machine where we set up all accounts to all of the others. This machine is also the NIS master where all linux user accounts are made, and all the samba servers hosts are also using NIS.

We have set up an LDAP server (OpenLDAP) that mainly has been used for authentication against various internal web sites, and we are using LDAP Account Manager for administrating this. I would like to replace NIS (tested and works) and also the smbpasswd file with this, but I am confused with the SAMBA part of this. (SAMBA version 3)

The samba.org manual/wiki seems to assume domain and PDB, so you can log in to the Windows PCs etc. and to the shares on the file servers (and other resources). We don't need this. Preferably I would like to just have a bunch of file servers in a workgroup, using user accounts from LDAP, (and preferably not having to set separate passwords, but as I understand it Windows/Samba is using totally different hashing, so that is not possible).

To put it another way: I would like our smbd daemons to, instead of looking up a line in /etc/sbmpasswd as it does today, to look up an entry stored in LDAP.

Is this possible?